# Is it possible in qml to redraw content of the Canvas object?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I have a Canvas object, which onPaint method looks like this:

```
onPaint: {
    var ctx = getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Just fill the Canvas with white color.

After this, I want to draw a point on this Canvas when I press on some Button, can I just change the Canvas in the onClick method of the Button object? For me it looks like if I want to draw something on Canvas I need to call requestPaint(), but requestPaint() just will fill the all Canvas in white. So, I see one solution, I need to declare 
`property var point: [x, y]` and change the onPaint method to something like this:

```
onPaint: {
    var ctx = getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //pseudocode
    if point is not empty:
        ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1);
        ctx.fillRect(point.x, point.y, 1, 1)
}
```

Will it work? Is there a better way to do what I described?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you could create a null property, and use the signal that is emited when there is a change to invoke `requestPaint()`, and in `onPaint()` you draw a circle that emulates the point.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property var drawPoint: null
    onDrawPointChanged: canv.requestPaint()

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 9

        Button {
            height: 40
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: qsTr("Random Point")
            onClicked: drawPoint = Qt.point(Math.random()*canv.width ,Math.random()*canv.height);
        }

        Canvas {
            id: canv
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

                if(drawPoint !== null){
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(drawPoint.x, drawPoint.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                    ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1);
                    ctx.fill()
                    ctx.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```